# One variable row inside another variable row

Tags: php

I have following script:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`"
$q = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($q);
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `other_table`";
$q1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($q1);
$item = $row1[$row['username']];
```

How can I set one variable row inside another, since it does not work. Basically, I need to select username, and then select column with user username from other table, in which is written user points.

I was thinking about adding:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`"
$q = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($q);
$sql1 = "SELECT `".$row['username']."` FROM `other_table` WHERE `uid` = 1";
$q1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($q1);
$item = $row1[xxxxxxxxxx]; // DONT KNOW HOW TO DEFINE IT, so it takes out found variable (there is only one).
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: So I'm just going to use my imagination and assume the question here is this: *"Is there a pot of gold at the end of the rainbow?"* And to your question I would say, *"Maybe."*

Comment: Why would you have a column named as the value of a row - or at least, a column named with a username...?

Comment: What do you need? In the sample above, your $item receive $row1[NAME_OF_YOUR_USER_IN_DB].. is that what are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Guess you want something like

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.user_name = t2.user_name?
```

Think about using JOIN

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users;";
$q = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($q);

$sql1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM other_table where username='%s';", $row['username']);
$q1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($q1);
```

// now $row1 contains the tuple of this user and could access the variables are you would
// normally do e.g. $row1['ID']

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users AS u INNER JOIN other_table AS o ON u.username = o.username
```

I'm assuming you want to do this because you want to be able to access all the rows from either table where a particular user name is the same (e.g. the data from `users` where `username="john"` and the data from `other_table` where `username="john"` for all usernames). No need to nest a result set to do this, just use a `JOIN` statement and then you can access all the columns as if it was a single result set (because it is):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users AS u INNER JOIN other_table AS o ON u.username = o.username";
$q = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($q);

$item = $row['any_column'];
```

FYI you should list out the column you want to retrieve instead of using `*`, even if you want to retrieve them all, as it is better practice in case you add new columns in the future.