# Problems with a SQL SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [one variable row inside another variable row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538742/one-variable-row-inside-another-variable-row)

I have script something like -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`"
$q = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($q);
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `other_table`";
$q1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($q1);
$item = $row1[$row['username']];
```

How can I set one variable row inside another, since it don't work. Basically, I need to select username, and then select column with user username from other table, in which is written user points.

I was thinking about adding -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`"
$q = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($q);
$sql1 = "SELECT `".$row['username']."` FROM `other_table` WHERE `uid` = 1";
$q1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($q1);
$item = $row1[xxxxxxxxxx]; // DONT KNOW HOW TO DEFINE IT, so it takes out found variable (there is only one).
```

I have question already, but not with full info, and I don't know how to delete it :(!

Here is my table -

### Users

'id'--'name'
'1'--'Bil'
'2'--'Conor'
'3'--'Ilian'

### Other_table (which holds points for users)

'id'--'Bil'--'Conor'--'Ilian'
'1'--'2'--'3'--'55'

Don't ask, why I don't hold the points in the same table, since if I could, I would do that ;)!

Comment: @konsolenfreddy You can tell what the question is? Impressive. :D

Comment: Based on what you are asking, your `other_table` has a column for each user? So if you had users `Bill`, `Jim` and `Jake` the `other_table` would have columns called `Bill`, `Jim`, `Jake` and `uid` (and maybe some others), am I correct? Could you list your table structures?

Comment: @Chris: easy enough to click a username and see what they've asked. In this case, only two questions that turn out to be identical (except in title).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to redesign the tables to start with, I would suggest a table structure like this:

```
Table Users
ID | Name

Table Points
UserID | Points
```

This way you can add a foreign key constraint between the tables and then do a simple join query like:

```
SELECT U.Name, P.Points FROM Users AS U INNER JOIN Points AS P ON U.ID = P.UserID
```

Then your php code would look like:

```
$sql = "SELECT U.Name, P.Points FROM Users AS U INNER JOIN Points AS P ON U.ID = P.UserID";
$q = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($q);
```

Here are the create table queries for you:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))
CREATE TABLE Points (UserID INT NOT NULL, Points INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(UserID) REFERENCES Users(ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

**EDIT**:

This should allow you to get the value (NOTE: untested as I don't have a php/mysql instance to mess with currently), but for a more robust solution you really should look into redesigning your table schema.

```
$userName = $row['username'];
$sql1 = "SELECT [". $userName ."] FROM other_table WHERE [uid] = 1";
$q1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($q1);
$item = $row1[$userName];
```

Comment: This one won't work for me. If you will tell me how to get the value from this query - $sql1 = "SELECT `".$row['username']."` FROM `other_table` WHERE `uid` = 1"; It will work.

Comment: Mate, it won't work for my case :(! Read one comment above :(

Comment: Why can't you change the design. You could add the `uid` column to the Points table and then you can index on the `(UserID, uid)` value and perform a lookup for each user and each uid. With your current design if you add a new user you have to alter the points table to add a new column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, other_table.points FROM users LEFT JOIN other_table ON other_table.name=users.name
```